# Не склоняется месяц на странице выборов

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election

Месяц не склоняется.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Май, оу, май, ду ю вонна сэй гудбай.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ забавно, что в графе "голосование началось" минуты нормально склоняются.

Comment: так минуты, это ж не месяц.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и не поспоришь...